# How to store user input into vectors with pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

I'm trying to solve this task whole day now, but I just can't and need some help.
The task is:
Write a program that requires the user to enter random number of people. For each person enter their name and age, and for the apartment - number of rooms and the area of apartment. Print on the screen the names of people with two-room apartments and the area of apartment.

Note: Each person's apartment should be a pointer to an object in a Class Apartment  in the Person class. The people entered by the console should be stored in a Vector with pointers to objects from class Person.

I'm confused with pointers and vectors.
He's my code so far. I know it's messy and bad..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Apartment {
private:
     int nRooms; // - number of rooms
    double q; // - area of apartment

public:
    Apartment(int nr, double qq)
    {nRooms = nr; q = qq;}
    int get_nRooms() { return nRooms; }
    double get_q() { return q; }
};

class Person{
private:
    string name;
    int age;
    Apartment* apartment;

public:
    Person(string n, int a, Apartment* ap)
    {name = n; age = a; apartment = ap;}

    string getName(){return name;}
    int getAge(){return age;}
    Apartment* setApartment(Apartment *);
    Apartment* getApartment(){return apartment;}
};

int main() {
    vector<Person*> ps;
    string n; // - person's name
    int age, nr; // nr - number of rooms
    double q; // area of apartment

while (cin >> n >> age >> nr >> q){
    if (nr == 2) {
        cout << "People with 2 room apartments:" << n << " " << endl;
        cout << "And their quadrature: " << q << endl;
        } 

}

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please pare your code down to a [mcve]. Also describe the exact errors you are getting.

Comment: Im not getting errors (for now), i just dont know how to store user input into vector

Comment: (btw hardest name to @). allocate a `Person*` and then use `vector::push_back`? This is a very basic operation, that should have been covered in your class/book/tutorial

Comment: Why is it that all these assignment questions people post about have so terrible design? A `std::vector` of pointers? Really? Sorry for the rant, but tell your teacher he should be ashamed of himself.

Comment: I know right, I often skip classes and study at home, but i still have to do these tasks..

Comment: Do you know, given a class, how to make an variable that is an object of that class? I.e. `Person aPerson /*things here*/;`?

Comment: Yes, but what else

Comment: Taking input into a temporary object and then pushing it into a vector?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create setters for each element as well in your classes.

Secondly your while loop logic is flawed. Do something like this

```
char continue_or_not c = 'y';

while(c == 'y')
{
  \\Take input by cin of each element
  \\make a temp person pointer
  \\make a new person and assign it all the values you input
  \\assign that person to that pointer
  \\copy that pointer to the vector (you will need a copy constructor for person as well because it has a pointer in it)
  \\take input in 'c' again and each iterating

}
```